# Did the "-ālis" and "-āris" suffixes have the same meaning in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, meaning, suffixes, spanish

In Spanish we have two suffixes *[-al](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1PYY1SR)* and *[-ar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3NNxyGS)* with the same meaning: "after a noun it indicates an abundance of the original word". So from *naranjo* ('orange tree') we have *naranjal* ('a group of orange trees'), and from *melón* ('melon') we have *melonar* ('a melon plantation').

Both suffixes come respectively from Latin *-ālis* and *-āris*. So what I want to know is:

- Did both suffixes have the same meaning in the Classical Latin language as it happens in Spanish?
- If so, was the meaning the one of "abundance" stated above? And was there a rule to know when to use the *-ālis* sufix and when to use the *-āris* suffix?

Comment: It seems plausible to me that some of the *-ar* come from *-arium*. Consider *donarium, aerarium, herbarium, librarium, panarium, vivarium, violarium, rosarium, seminarium, spoliarium*, which are places where something is stored or otherwise abundant. This is quite different from *-aris*. At least *melonar* sounds like *-arium* instead of *-aris* to me. Do you want to include *-arium* in the question or leave it out?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta the _-arium_ suffix seems different, and derived into the Spanish suffix _-ario_ as in _erario_, _herbario_, _rosario_, _seminario_ and others. It seems to be "place (or building) where the original noun is stored" more than just "an abundance of the original noun".

Answer (score 8):

They not only had the same meaning in Latin, they were the same suffix.

In Latin, the suffix *-āli-* (the *-s* at the end is the nominative ending, so not part of the suffix) formed adjectives from nouns. But when there was an *l* in the stem of the noun it was attached to, the suffix became *-āri-* by dissimilation: e.g. *familia - familiāris*. This is why Spanish *melonar* has *-r* rather than *-l*.

The meaning was more general than "abundant with [noun]" (as I believe is still the case in Spanish); these adjectives could mean "having to do with / associated with [noun]", "having [noun]", etc. Some examples (from Weiss 2009:518-9):

- *mors* "death" - *mortālis* "mortal"
- *annus* "year" - *annālis* "yearly"
- *anima* "soul" - *animālis* "animate"
- *mīles* "soldier" - *mīlitāris* "military"